# How can I preserve my objects when writing code to a WorkSheet Module?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the WorkBook_NewSheet event to add a worksheet. Here is my event code
...

```
Private Sub thisWbk_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    If SkipWBEvent = True Then Exit Sub

    If TypeOf Sh Is Worksheet Then
        Set oWks = Sh
    End If
 
    Dim objEvents As EventsObject
    Dim WBEvents As EventsWB

    RaiseEvent objSender.GetEvents(objEvents)

    Set WBEvents = objEvents.WBEvents

    RaiseEvent WBEvents.WBNewSheet(oWks)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    With New WSModuleCode
        .LoadModuleCode oWks
    End With

End Sub
```

...
The code runs as expected and another worksheet is added. The process also performs some formatting and column width changes. When LoadModuleCode is called, the code I need to run a SelectionChange is added to the worksheet module.
...

```
Public Sub LoadModuleCode(ByRef Wks As Worksheet)

Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim SheetMod As CodeModule

    With ActiveWbk.VBProject
        Set VBComp = .VBComponents(Wks.CodeName)
    End With

    Set SheetMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    With SheetMod

        If .CountOfDeclarationLines <= 2 Then
            SheetCode SheetMod, Wks
        End If

    End With

End Sub

Private Sub SheetCode(ByRef SheetMod As CodeModule, ByRef Wks As Worksheet)

Dim ProcString As String
Dim l As Long
Dim EnumSheet As SheetEnum

Const A  As String = "SheetModuleCode"

On Error GoTo EH
    
TryAgain:

    EnumSheet = SourceTyper.SheetType(Wks)
        
    Const SChArgs As String = "(ByVal Target As Range)"
    Const ConName = "WorkSheet"
        
    Select Case EnumSheet
     
        Case MainSheet, VSELSheet
                          
            ProcString = "Private Sub " & ConName & "_SelectionChange" & SChArgs
                                          
         Case Else
         
             'For expansion?
     
     End Select
            
     With SheetMod
     
         l = .CountOfLines
         
         .InsertLines l + 1, ProcString
         
         .InsertLines l + 2, ""
         .InsertLines l + 3, "Dim oWks As Worksheet"
         .InsertLines l + 4, "Dim objController As Controller"
         .InsertLines l + 5, ""
         .InsertLines l + 6, "If SkipWSEvent = True Then Exit Sub"
         .InsertLines l + 7, ""
         .InsertLines l + 8, "Set oWks = Target.Parent"
         .InsertLines l + 9, "Set objController = TheController"
         .InsertLines l + 10, ""
         .InsertLines l + 11, "If Not objController.ActiveParent Is oWks Then"
         .InsertLines l + 12, "objController.InitializeSources oWks"
         .InsertLines l + 13, "End If"
         .InsertLines l + 14, ""
         .InsertLines l + 15, "SkipControlEvent = False"
         .InsertLines l + 16, "SkipWSEvent = False"
         .InsertLines l + 17, "Application.EnableEvents = True"
         .InsertLines l + 18, ""
         
         .InsertLines l + 19, "End Sub"
         
     End With
    
Exit Sub

EH:

    MsgBox Application.VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule.Name & " " & A
    
    MsgBox "Error Line: " & Erl & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
         "Error: (" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description, vbCritical

    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

    GoTo TryAgain

End Sub
```

...

Immediately after this code is run, the WorkSheet_SelectionChange event header and code is added to the worksheet module. However, at that point, all code execution ceases and all objects, anywhere in the project, no matter when they were made, are all killed. This interrupts the column sizing and final formatting, even though the problem code is run at the very end.

Because the new sheets are added dynamically, I cannot hard-write the code I need in the added sheet module. My workaround may be to run the LoadModuleCode on the next sheet selection event. It will still kill all my objects but once the code is added, the event will remake everything. This will mean an extra sheet click before everything is back to normal. Is there a way to hide my objects from the compiler when it recompiles the module code? Thank You

**My Workaround**

I found a satisfactory workaround for my specific issue. I moved the With block that adds the WSModuleCode from the Workbook_NewSheet event so that it now runs at the end of the button click event which initiates the new sheet addition. So, the new sheet gets added and this code gets added to the sheet module, which kills all the objects. But, this code allows the next Worksheet_SelectionChange event for the sheet to recreate them.

Comment: Why not use a (hidden) sheet, with the code already added, as a template?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what is supposed to be happening here, but I'm pretty sure what you need to do is code a class module that gets passed the target sheet.

Comment: You can make a class persistent using the predeclared attribute. Check this [article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/07/08/about-class-modules/) and use [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com/) to make it work easier.

Comment: Tim, I am using a template for now, but since the sheets are added or deleted by the user, I wanted to add the event stub at runtime. I just don't understand why the control dictionary dies when this happens.

Comment: Adding code at run-time can sometimes result in a re-compile of the project. I have never understood exactly what triggers it though.  If you have template sheets then you should be able to detect when the user adds a new sheet and then replace that sheet with a copy of your template?

Comment: Hi Ricardo..I tried your suggestion and set the Predeclared ID of my WSModuleCode object to True and tried to use the object to hold an instance of itself, but it didn't make a difference. Every object still dies and has to be renewed.